# How to remove a key and a value out of an javascript object

Tags: javascript

If I had a javascript object  with the values of

```
{"__v":0,"_id":"528277c808cab8ac2b000001","password":"password",
"userId":5,"userName":"Austinsss","$$hashKey":"00F"}
```

How could I remove "$$hashKey":"00F" out of the object entirely.

Comment: use **delete** operator

Comment: this is probably a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate I suppose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delete` it!

```
delete objname["$$hashKey"];
```

Comment: Answer first so you get the points. Though thanks everyone for there quick responses.

Comment: First answers aren't always the best ones. Bear that in mind for your future questions

Comment: It's true, @Bojangles answer was more detailed than mine was, and I'm pretty sure I wasn't the first. But thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use [`delete`<sup>(MDN)</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

```
var foo = {"__v":0,"_id":"528277c808cab8ac2b000001","password":"password",
"userId":5,"userName":"Austinsss","$$hashKey":"00F"};

delete foo.$$hashKey;
```

You could also use bracket notation if you have keys with odd characters in them:

```
delete foo['$$HashKey'];
```

Comment: I think it's most commonly referred to as *bracket notation*.

Comment: Thanks, updated. I wasn't sure what to go with, an "array notation" will confuse people

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
delete obj.$$hashKey
```